# Javascript pop-up window onclick not closing [RGBA]

Tags: javascript, css

Mask CSS

```
#mask {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#cc000000',GradientType=1 );
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Now the function to close my mask.

```
$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .afspraak-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  
    });
    return false;
    });
```

When I click my div which contains an `a href`, it will automatically show a pop-up with a opacity mask behind the pop-up.

Now when I want to close the pop-up I'll have to click on the mask to let it dissapear.

My problem is that internet explorer doesn't accept my rgba opacity so I'm not able to click on my mask to let my pop-up dissapear. But without rgba, internet explorer will not show any opacity css.

Any tips would be helpfull.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, delete: `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);` and `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#cc000000',GradientType=1 );`

Change that to:

```
background-color: #000;
opacity:0.8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80);
```